# Can I read a file into different partitions in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use spark for data processing for my big data but spark opens excessive amount of connection to my database resulting in overload. Is it possible to create empty partitions and read the desired data into them? With some function like forEachPartition? (This should be in initial reading stage which means I can not read the data fully and then make changes)

Comment: try to use the timestamp column to read data in batch . will reduce the bottleneck of spawning process on db.

Comment: mapPartitions() – This is exactly the same as map(); the difference being, Spark mapPartitions() provides a facility to do heavy initializations (for example Database connection) once for each partition instead of doing it on every DataFrame row. This helps the performance of the job when you dealing with heavy-weighted initialization on larger datasets [source](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-map-vs-mappartitions-transformation/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are facing issue with too many connection to the database.
you can refer this official documentation : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

you need to set the `numPartitions` property which controls the number of parallel connections to the database and also you can configure the `partitionColumn`, `lowerBound` and `upperBound` to get more control over the partition size in spark dataframe.